# nodejs - merging 2 or more modules

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to merge 2 or more modules into a single module by requiring the second module something like this:

#### module1.js

```
var xx = require('somemodule');
var yy = require('anothermodule');
module.exports = function(x,y){
    var1:'defg';
    var2:'efgh';
    aa = function(x,y){
        do something different
    }
}
```

#### module.js

```
var xx = require('somemodule');
module.exports = function(x,y){
    var1:'abcd';
    var2:'efgh';
    aa = function(x,y){
        do something....
    }
}
require('module1.js');
```

I am trying to come up with a way of having a standard module and in that module look for a custom.module, if it exists then override any existing vars and objects in the standard module with those from the custom module.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear about what you exactly you are looking for. But if you want to write a module to expose everything from another existing module, you can always try exporting the same module, and adding more attributes which you need into it, provided that the first module exports an object :

```
var xx = require('module.js');
xx.something = function(x,y) {
    ...
}
module.exports = xx;
```

Depending on what exactly you want, it might make also sense to use [prototypal inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) to make your object and export it.